# incomplete recursive snapshots on zfs

Tags: zfs, illumos, omnios

I got a bunch of new disks on one of our systems and wanted to
transfer an existing pool over to them so what I did was this:

```
zfs snapshot -r old-pool@replicaton
zfs send -R old-pool@replication | mbuffer -m 1G  | zfs receive -F -d  new-pool
```

but then halfway through the operation, I got a warning from `zfs send`, complaining
that the snapshot `old-pool/some/fileset@replication` would not exist ...

when I went to investigate, I found indeed that `zfs snapshot -r` had
neglected to create a snapshot on `old-pool/some/fileset`. So I
ran

```
zfs list -r -o name old-pool | \
xargs -n1 perl -e 'system "zfs","list",$ARGV[0]."\@replication"'
```

and found that there were about 10% of the filesets which were
lacking this snapshot ...

I then proceeded to create the missing snapshot individually, and
it worked fine.

I have since repeated the experiment and found the same problem
again ...

Any idea how this can be?

This is happening on omnios r151010

Answer (score 7):

OH MY! How embarrassing ... I found the reason ...

The pool (old-pool) I am trying to replicate is itself a backup store, receiving regular updates via `zfs receive -F`

So while my recursive snapshot was initially complete, it got "cleaned out" as new snapshots were being integrated into individual filesets.

Once I stopped the backup script that was sending snapshots to `old-pool`, the world was working as expected again.